# Set programmatically location by Wi-Fi in Android

Tags: android, gps, location, wifi

I have an application with gps and wireless permissions.I want to set programmatically location with gps satellites and location determined by Wi-Fi.

I`m done with gps satellites :

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

Can I do something like that with location determined by Wi-Fi ?

Comment: see this http://androidfreakers.blogspot.in/2011/09/enable-or-disable-gps-in-android.html

Comment: Ok, for gps location, but location determined by wi-fi ?

Comment: Do you mean to turn on the wifi programmatically?

Comment: Settings->Location Services and there you have 3 options : 1.Use wireless networks; 2.use GPS satellites; 3.Location and Google search.And I want to turn on programmatically 1.